# Get internal size of an (infragistics Winforms 10.2) control with scrollbars in C#

Tags: c#, .net, infragistics

How can I get the internal size of an (infragistics) control with scrollbars?

The `control.Size` contains the control size on the screen but how do I get the internal size (total size behind the scrollbars)?

Thanks,

Comment: what is your platform? the correct answer depends on this information.

Comment: I think he means WPF, WinForms or ASP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible: http://community.infragistics.com/forums/p/47007/251654.aspx#251654